# Dynamically load Angular template in `Component` decorator

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to load angular template dynamically like this:

```
import { getHTMLTemplate } from './util';

const dynamicTemplate = getHTMLTemplate(); 

@Component({
    selector: 'app-button',
    // templateUrl: './button.component.html',
    template: `
        <div">
            some div
        </div>
        ${dynamicTemplate}
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./button.component.less'],
})
```

`getHTMLTemplate` implementation:

```
export function getHTMLTemplate(){
    return `<div>dynamic div</div>`;
};
```

This works fine on `ng serve`, but fails on `ng build`.
It throws following error:

```
src/util.ts(5,32): Error during template compile of 'AppComponent'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getHTMLTemplate' was called.
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is designed to achieve what the OP is after in a different way.
You can create a property on the component which contains the HTML string.
You can then use 'moustaches' in the component's template interpolate the string :

`<div innerHtml="{{propertyName}}"></div>`

You can also use property binding:
`<div [innerHtml] = "propertyName"></div>`

If the string is coming in dynamically, you will need use the property binding option, and inject DOMSanitizer to  bring in html containing style tags.

DOMSanitizer has a few methods available (found in '@angular/platform-browser') for returning safe html, scripts ,  styles and some others.

Hope this helps

Comment: He is trying to compile a dynamic template, not just html.

Comment: Yes. I just edited my answer actually, my understanding is now better than it was when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

As error says, use function not the function expression:

`getHTMLTemplate` implementation:

```
export const getHTMLTemplate = () => {
    return `<div>dynamic div</div>`;
};
```

**To Be:**

```
export const getHTMLTemplate() {
    return `<div>dynamic div</div>`;
};
```

Comment: Now Ia am getting ` Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getHTMLTemplate' was called.`

Answer (score 0):

Without holding the function ref in a `const` ([source](https://github.com/amcdnl/ngrx-actions/issues/23#issuecomment-359738290)) Try :

```
export  function getHTMLTemplate() {
    return `<div>dynamic div</div>`;
};
```

---

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-button',
    // templateUrl: './button.component.html',
    template: `
        <div">
            some div
        </div>
        ${getHTMLTemplate()}
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./button.component.less'],
})
```

**[working demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzknuj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Comment: Now I am getting `Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getHTMLTemplate' was called.`

Comment: That's `function` not `const` @AkshayM

Comment: I am using `function`, you can check updated question.

Comment: @AkshayM the problem is that AoT is very strict, and requires a function declaration, not a const that holds a function reference.

Comment: @AkshayM but the demo there is working, how come not working ?

Comment: Yes your example works. But now in my case, I am getting `@ngrx/store/store.ts(590,5): Error during template compile of 'createFeatureSelector'` in many files.

Comment: Strange isn't it.

Comment: @AkshayM that has no direct relation with your first error, even it is not the same.

Comment: When I used it like you suggested.

Comment: @AkshayM, that's why i'd said no `direct` relation, maybe the fix u'd had emerged other misimplementation, e.g: `createFeatureSelector`, i do not see anything in ur question about it. whether you ask an independant other question or u update ur current one WHERE in both cases you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).