# Dynamically load angular template string in component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to load angular template dynamically like this:

```
import { getHTMLTemplate } from './util';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-button',
    // templateUrl: './button.component.html',
    template: `
        <div>
            some div
        </div>
        ${getHTMLTemplate()}
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./button.component.less'],
})
```

`getHTMLTemplate` implementation:

```
export function getHTMLTemplate(){
    return getTemplateWithSomeComplexLogic();
};

export function getTemplateWithSomeComplexLogic() {
    return '<app-something>dynamic template</app-something>';
}
```

This works fine on `ng serve`, but fails on `ng build`.
It throws following error:

```
  Error during template compile of 'getHTMLTemplate'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getTemplateWithSomeComplexLogic' was called.
```

Comment: I think, getTemplateWithSomeComplexLogic is using another component , which isn't loaded . have u included the dynamic component in your App module ?.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865582/dynamically-load-angular-template-in-component-decorator